# Calculate data by each month,year and Group by something

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have 3 table and I want to get below result
in book_table isbn is Pk
in order_table orderid is Pk
in order_detail_table orderid&itemno are Pk and isbn and orderid are Fk

book_table

```
isbn    title          edition_no   price
1001    Database Manage     2       95
1111    Fundamentals of     3       75
2002    Database System     2       90
2222    Database Princi     1       50
3003    Database System     4       100
3333    Principles of D     1       100
4004    Database Modeli     2       70
4444    Principles of D     2       60
5555    Object_Relation     1       75
6666    Principles of D     1       65
7777    Readings in Dat     1       65
```

order_table

```
orderid orderdate
1       1998-03-01
2       1999-03-01
3       1999-03-01
4       1999-03-12
5       1999-03-08
6       1999-03-10
7       1999-03-12
8       1999-03-11
```

order_details_table

```
orderid item_no isbn    quantity    customerid
1           1   2222    1               1
1           2   4444    2               1
1           3   6666    2               1
1           4   8888    1               1
1           5   1111    1               1
1           6   1001    1               1
1           7   2002    1               1
1           8   3003    1               1
1           9   4004    1               1
1           10  5555    1               1
```

and result have to be

```
Month_rank year_rank  Month_total   year_total    month       year
1            1        14580.00     17505.00       March       2004
2            1        2925.00      17505.00       January     2004
1            2        9320.00      17490.00       March       2002
2            2        7090.00      17490.00       August      2002
3            2        825.00       17490.00       September   2002
4            2        175.00       17490.00       January     2002
. . .
```

what query given this result.

and second query for result below
what query give result below

```
AMOUNT_MONEY            MONTH            YEAR
14040.00                   -               -
130.00                     -             1998
975.00                     -             1999
1365.00                    -             2000
390.00                     -             2001
7930.00                    -             2002
2405.00                    -             2003
845.00                     -             2004
130.00                  March            1998
260.00                  January          1999
```

Comment: What code have you tried?, what version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
WITH month_totals AS (
    SELECT t.order_month, month_total = SUM(t.amount)
    FROM (
        SELECT order_month = DATEADD(day, -(DAY(o.orderdate) - 1), o.orderdate), amount = od.quantity * b.price
        FROM book_table b
        INNER JOIN order_details_table od
        ON b.isbn = od.isbn
        INNER JOIN order_table o
        ON o.orderid = od.orderid
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.order_month
),
year_totals AS (
    SELECT order_year = YEAR(o.orderdate), year_total = SUM(od.quantity * b.price)
    FROM book_table b
    INNER JOIN order_details_table od
    ON b.isbn = od.isbn
    INNER JOIN order_table o
    ON o.orderid = od.orderid
    GROUP BY YEAR(o.orderdate)
)
SELECT mt.month_rank, yt.year_rank, mt.month_total, yt.year_total, 
    [month] = DATENAME(MONTH, mt.order_month), [year] = order_year
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, year_rank = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.year_total DESC)
    FROM year_totals t
) yt
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t.*, month_rank = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(t.order_month) ORDER BY t.month_total DESC)
    FROM month_totals t
) mt
ON yt.order_year = YEAR(mt.order_month)
ORDER BY yt.year_rank, mt.month_rank
```

Comment: this query  for all of Month give 'January'

Comment: @Naghibi - my bad, DATENAME takes an actual date, not the element ordinal - try the corrected version. That said, are the numbers grouped as you expected? I couldn't be completely sure because your sample source data wasn't enough to produce your example result set (you quoted the items for a single order only).

Answer (score 0):

Get your "year" query working separately. Then get your "month" query working separately. Then add the "year" query to the "month". This can be done by having adding the "year" query to the "month" query as a "join subquery".

There are many other ways but this keeps everything based on two simple queries.